# WaitForSingleObject return ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c#, winapi, waitforsingleobject

I'm trying to determine if a process is still alive (at the moment I did check, I'm aware it can be closed right after I do the check) by calling [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx) with a handle get from [`Process.MainWindowHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) which works just fine with [`IsIconic()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527(v=vs.85).aspx) but it return `WAIT_FAILED` and [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx) a `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`

```
UInt32 r = WaitForSingleObject(handle, 0);
if(r == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("still running!");
}
if(r == WAIT_FAILED)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling WaitForSingleObject from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718217/calling-waitforsingleobject-from-c-sharp)

Comment: You can't wait on a window's handle. Check the docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx for the types of handles that can be waited on..

Comment: The system says that your handle is not valid. Your handle is not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot wait on a window handle. You can pass window handles to window-related functions, like `IsIconic()`, but they are not kernel objects so you cannot wait on them. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) gives a list of objects that you can wait on:

> The WaitForSingleObject function can wait for the following objects:
>
> - Change notification
> - Console input
> - Event
> - Memory resource notification
> - Mutex
> - Process
> - Semaphore
> - Thread
> - Waitable timer

So, if you want to wait on a process until it ends, you can wait on the process's handle, which is accessible via the [`Process.Handle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.handle.aspx) property.

But you don't actually need to P/Invoke the Win32 function at all. The .NET `Process` wrapper class has [`WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) and [`WaitForInputIdle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx) member functions that can be used to wait on a process (note that both have overloads taking a timeout value).

If this is a process that you started using the `Process` class wrapper, you can simply interrogate the [`Process.HasExited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) property.

Comment: If you have a `Process` object, shouldn't you be able to use `HasExited` regardless of whether you were the one who actually spawned the process? I don't see why it should care if the caller is also the spawner.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't want wait until it exit, haven't started the process too. I want to check if a determined process is still alive at a particular time before doing some action (it happens every x seconds)

Comment: @remy The reason I wrote that is I remember reading somewhere that this didn't work. Presumably the Process class doesn't track this information unless it starts the process. Looking to corroborate my memory, I found [this how-to article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y111seb2.aspx), which says at the top: *"Note: This value is only returned for processes that are started by a Process component."* That may not be entirely true; you'd need to check the reference source to be absolutely certain.

Comment: @jack Then it sounds like you have a good old-fashioned race condition. Checking if the process is alive won't do you a lot of good in that case. Just try to perform the action and handle failures gracefully. It also sounds suspiciously to me like you might be trying to implement this via polling, which is pretty much always a bad design.

Comment: @Jack by definition, a process is still alive if it has not exited yet. So either check `HasExited`, or like Cody said, you can call `WaitForExit()` with a timeout: "*If you pass 0 (zero) to the method, it returns true only if the process has already exited; otherwise, it immediately returns false*". That is the same effect as calling `WaitForSingleObject()` with a 0ms timeout.